# localhost port is not working although the code is responding in console

Tags: node.js

I have done everything correct. it is also working in console.log but not in browser in localport. please help

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.send("Hi there, welcome to my assingment");
})
app.get("/speak/goat", function(req, res){
    res.send('The goat says "Oink"');
})
app.get("/speak/dog", function(req, res){
    res.send('The dog says "Bow"');
})
app.get("/speak/goat", function(req, res){
    res.send('The goat says "Oink"');
})
app.get("/repeat/:anything/:value", function(req, res){
    var anyThing = req.params.anything;
    var value = req.params.number.value;
    for(i = 0 ; i >= value ;i++ ){
        res.send(anyThing);
    }

})
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 6000;
app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("hello " + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to open the localhost:6000 on chrome which is resulting into "ERR_UNSAFE_PORT" - Its because of using a NON STANDARD PORT.
You can use different port example 3000 or 4000 or even 6001. 
 - Internet explorer works on port 6000 :-)

find more here https://douglastarr.com/how-to-allow-unsafe-ports-in-chrome